# Put PreferenceActivity in a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, preferences

I'm currently working on an app with a navigation drawer, however the settings of this app are displayed in a separated activity.

How can I display those preferences in a fragment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

If you want to make your code re-usable, make your own PreferenceFragment, and use it in a CustomPreferenceActivity.